# python - Why do sets and dequeu require brackets when adding an integer on initialization, but don't if you use .add later?

Tags: python, set, deque

Bit of a pedantic question, but in Python,
why do Sets and Dequeues seem to have this feature?

I saw someone else do this:

```
amount = 5  
seen = set([amount])
```

But I do this:

```
amount = 5
seen = set()
seen.add(amount)
```

**but**
`seen = set((amount))` returns a type Error int is not iterable.

`help(set.add)` just says :
Help on method_descriptor:

```
add(...)
    Add an element to a set.
    
    This has no effect if the element is already present.
(END)
```

I saw code where someone added an element on initialization, and I wanted to see how it works.  Do the square brackets add iterable to the object? And does .add do the same?

Which is better?

Comment: Side-note: The normal way to initialize a non-empty `set` with a fixed set of initial values is to skip the `set` constructor entirely, replacing `set([amount])` (or equivalently, `set((amount,))`) with `{amount}`.

Answer (score 0):

The first two code fragments have equivalent functionality. The inner parentheses in the third fragment are irrelevant. Maybe you meant *seen = set((amount,))* See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set